# "copy" elements of array in order into an "int"? C

Tags: c, arrays, integer

It may be a really simple question, but I need to copy two int values that are in array[0] and array[1] into a single integer.

As instance if array[0]=1 and array[1]=6, I need the integer to be equal to "16".
Any element of the array has a range from 0 to 9.

What chances do I have?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: What is `array[0]` is 21 and `array[1]` is 416? And do make sure you understand the place-value system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does array[0] always represent the 10's place and array[1] always represent the 1's place?  Will array[0] or array[1] ever have a value greater than 9 or less than 0?  Will there ever be an array[2] or an array[3] to represent a 3 digit or a 4 digit number?

If the answer to the above questions are Yes, No, and No, then isn't the answer simple arithmetic?

```
int result = (array[0] * 10) + array[1];
```

If the data isn't pre range-checked, then you'll need to add that step.  Even if the data IS pre range-checked, you should consider adding that step anyway to make extra sure.

'10' is also a magic number in the above example.  It would probably be wise to not hard-code 10, but base it off of the size of the array.  Consider the case where there IS an array[2] . . . array[n].  What then?

Comment: I said it may be a simple question :P This is exactly what I was needing. Thank you so much!! As soon as the site let me accept the answer, I will.

Comment: If you had 21 in the array[0] and array[1] is 416 you will have 626. Shouldn't it be 21416?

Comment: It would depend on the specified ranges of the inputs, of course.  The spec, as written, is obviously ambiguous and needs to be tightened up.  Maybe, when array[0] is 21, you're supposed to multiply the two together!  Shouldn't it be 8736?

Comment: Fair enough, I just read it after.

Comment: This raises a good point.  My assumptions upon reading the problem was that the array represented base-10 digits.  Your assumptions are that the digits need to be concatenated, regardless of the length.  This is why it's important, when asking a question, to throw in some information about WHY you're trying to do something.  Without that extra information, it's easy to latch onto a solution that you THINK is the answer, but does nothing to effectively mitigate the underlying problem!

Comment: The range is from 0 to 9 that's why this is the solution in this case. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @PeteBaughman Yep, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Pete, you are right. I will have that in mind when making a new question. However, you DID understand.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it, is to convert your integers to strings, contact than, and then convert again, this time from string to int.

```
char s1[30]; // String that will hold the first integer
char s2[15]; // String that will hold the second integer

int intResult;
```

First convert int to string:

```
sprintf(s1, "%d", array[0]);
sprintf(s2, "%d", array[1]);
```

Than join the 2 strings together:

```
s1 = strcat(s1,s2);
```

Then convert the string result to integer.
    intResult = atoi(s1);