# How to store an integer in a single index of character array?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, atoi, itoa

I want to store a single integer in a single index of character array. The `itoa` function is not working in this case. Can anyone help?

Comment: what do you mean by "single integer in a single index"?

Comment: In a single *element* of a char array?

Comment: yes in a single element of character array
int num;
char arr[10];
arr[0]=num;
but i am not getting correct value..

Comment: Take a look into sprintf() function. Maybe this is what you seek http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: What if the integer is `5362`?

Comment: A character is not large enough to store all integers, so what is the range of `num`?

Comment: num is specified to 1 digit only

Comment: Are you doing the same homework [as this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13445222/596781)?

Comment: I assume that you mean 1 **decimal** digit, as oppose to binary, or hex or any other digit. So `num` is in the range `[0..9]` right? If so, you are probably are after doing this: `arr[0]='0' + num`

Answer (score 7):

If you mean that you want to use the integer as a character value and put it in an array, then it's just

```
array[index] = number;
```

If you mean you want to write the value of a single-digit number into a particular index of an array, then

```
if (number >= 0 && number < 10) {
    array[index] = '0' + number;
} else {
    // not representable by a single digit
}
```

**UPDATE**: From your comments, this is probably what you want.

If you mean that you want to write the decimal representation of the number into an array (covering several character elements, not just one), then don't use `itoa` because that's non-standard and dangerous. `snprintf` can do that more safely:

```
if (snprintf(array, array_size, "%d", number) >= array_size) {
    // the array was too small
}
```

or, since this is C++, you can use `std::string` to manage the memory for you and ensure the array is large enough:

```
std::string string = std::to_string(number);
```

or, if you're stuck with an out-dated C++ library

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << number;
std::string string = n.str();
```

If you mean something else, then please clarify.